# Insert an element between each two adjacent elements of Seq

Tags: scala

For example, I have  Seq(1,2,3) and I want to get Seq(1,0,2,0,3)

The first thing that comes to mind is:

```
  scala> Seq(1,2,3).flatMap(e => 0 :: e :: Nil).tail
  res17: Seq[Int] = List(1, 0, 2, 0, 3)
```

Is there any better/more elegant option?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try for comprehension:

```
for(i <- list; p <- List(0, i)) yield p
```

However you must somehow remove the first element (it yields: `0,1,0,2,0,3`), either by:

```
(for(i <- list; p <- List(0, i)) yield p).tail
```

or:

```
list.head :: (for(i <- list.tail; p <- List(0, i)) yield p)
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is another approach:

```
def intersperse[E](x: E, xs:Seq[E]): Seq[E] = (x, xs) match {
    case (_, Nil)     => Nil
    case (_, Seq(x))  => Seq(x) 
    case (sep, y::ys) => y+:sep+:intersperse(sep, ys)
}
```

which is safe over empty `Seq`s too.

Answer (score 0):

```
def intersperse[T](xs: List[T], item: T): List[T] = xs match {
  case Nil => xs
  case _ :: Nil => xs
  case a :: ys => a :: item :: intersperse(ys, item)
}
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, you should [edit] your answer to include an explanation of *how* this code block answers the question. This helps to provide context to those who come across the same issue later on.

Answer (score 0):

Can also use this extension:

```
implicit class SeqExtensions[A](val as: Seq[A]) extends AnyVal {

  def intersperse(a: A): Seq[A] = {
    val b = Seq.newBuilder[A]
    val it = as.iterator

    if (it.hasNext) {
      b += it.next()
      while(it.hasNext) {
        b += a
        b += it.next()
      }
    }

    b.result()
  }

}
```